# Jquery menu - toggle problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

To see what is the trouble see code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ljuboja/hNddK/).Is there a way to set list with class "menutop" to act like "toogle" class (+), in other words  when click Posts, pages and so on submenu is revealed.

Second thing that bothers me is how to set menu to behave in way that when one submenu is opened, and user click some other submenu, the previous opened to be closed automatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named the function in the toogle handler and called it from menutop setting the toggle class element as "this" so it looks more familiar to you.

I just added a line that ensures that only one section could be open at a time

```
function hitMe(){
   if ($(this) .hasClass('toggle-open')) {
     $(this) .removeClass('toggle-open') .addClass('toggle-closed') .empty('') .append('+') .parents('li') .children('ul') .slideUp(250);
     $(this) .parent('.menutop') .removeClass('menutop-open') .addClass('menutop-closed');
   }else{
     $(".toggle-open").parent().click();//closes the previously opened menu
     $(this) .parent('.menutop') .removeClass('menutop-closed') .addClass('menutop-open');
     $(this) .removeClass('toggle-closed') .addClass('toggle-open') .empty('') .append('&ndash;') .parents('li') .children('ul') .slideDown(250);
 }
}

$(".menutop").click(function(){
     hitMe.apply(
         $(this).find(".toggle")
     );
}
);
```

Comment: Great job.Is it possible when one of submenus item is clicked and new page is opened from that link, than that submenu stay toogle opened on new loaded page.
tnx

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a revision.](http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/5/) Added a close all function and then I also added a click handler for the menu-top class that does essentially the same thing to expand the tabs. Hope it helps!

Comment: thx for trying to help me.Work as i wanted, but new problem arised:now when click to close opened submenu-not working, and + its - constantly

Comment: Oh, forgot to change the text to '+'. Fixed it here http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/24/ . I also added an alert on the submenu click which seems to be working. What do you mean it isn't working?

Comment: When I click on + everything is ok but then when click again on now - text its still stay - and submenu is revealed insted of to be closed and text change to +

Comment: Dang, I realized I made a couple of mistakes. You don't need the click handler for the +/- since it's contained in the menu. Also, you should just call the closeAll() if it's already open. This should be better http://jsfiddle.net/hNddK/25/

Comment: dont work again, sorry. submenu dont close itself when another is selected, it worked in previous attempts to get this thing to work.

Comment: @aaron-hathaway Is it possible when one of submenus item is clicked and new page is opened from that link, than that submenu stay toogle opened on new loaded page